# Regular expression to find all words not inside quotes and put them inside quotes

Tags: regex, unix, sublimetext2

I have a list of words like this:

```
AccountDescriptiveName,
AccountDescriptiveName,
AdGroupName,
AdGroupStatus,
ApprovalStatus,
AverageCpc,
AverageCpm,
AveragePosition,
BiddingStrategyType,
CampaignId,
CampaignStatus,
ClickConversionRate,
ConversionRateManyPerClick,
ConversionsManyPerClick,
ConversionValue,
ConvertedClicks,
Cost,
CostPerConversionManyPerClick,
CostPerConvertedClick,
CpcBid,
CpcBidSource,
Criteria,
Ctr,
EnhancedCpcEnabled,
FirstPageCpc,
Id,
IsNegative,
KeywordMatchType,
LabelIds,
Labels,
QualityScore,
```

I am using Sublime Text and want use a regex to put them all inside quotes so they look like this:

```
'AccountDescriptiveName',
'AccountDescriptiveName',
'AdGroupName',
```

and so on.

I have the find which is: `(\w+)` but cannot figure out the replace.

Comment: Ah, I was hitting replace rather than replace all so that wasnt working originally. Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to backreference the match group inside the replacement call:

```
Replace: "\1"
```